# How do you deploy your Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Do you upload your rail application to your host via FTP first?

I'm currently using Passenger and Capistrano. If I do "cap deploy" in my local machine then I think Capistrano should upload my rail application to my host, right?

Someone from my host is saying that I need to run "cap deploy" in server. I think it doesn't make sense.

Comment: yeah, they're wrong....  you run cap deploy from your own machine.  As i said in another thread of yours, I now deploy to Heroku, which involves typing "git push heroku master" and that's it.  If you can't get capistrano working, then you can always just FTP everything and you'll be fine...  but it's a hassle.  and so not the rails way....

Comment: :) how did you fed up in this site? man..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to run cap deloy on your local machine and that should get the current version of your software to the server. However, you need to set up first how this is supposed to happen. I for example use Git to manage my code and also use it to get my software on the server. However, you could also use SVN or FTP if you prefer that. If you google for Capistrano together with the Software youbeant to transfer the code with and maybe even your hosting providers name, you probably will find a decent step by step explanation. For me John Numemaker's post on deploying with Capistrano and Git on Dreamhost really helped: http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2008/12/14/deploying-rails-on-dreamhost-with-passenger/

As an alternative you also might want to check out heroku.com. Their smallest offer is free and enough for most projects. The deployment process is so easy a monkey could deploy a Rails app on their platform. I generally can only recommend heroku.

Comment: Thanks. I have read this article as well. He doesn't mention whether he run "cap deploy:setup" on server or local machine or not. That's making me confused. Yes. I'm using GitHub Private Account and Dreamhost.